# How to use TextInputLayout & TextInputEditText in Kotlin anko

Tags: android, kotlin, anko

```
Error:(63, 13) Unresolved reference: textInputLayout
Error:(64, 17) Unresolved reference: textInputEditText
```

I'm getting above error message when trying to add textInputLayout & textInputEditText  in kotlin anko.
Below is my code -

```
private fun test(context: Context): View{
    return with(context){
        verticalLayout {
            textInputLayout {
                textInputEditText{}
            }
        }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a kotlin code file anywhere you wish. Put below code without any class declaration.

```
inline fun ViewManager.textInputEditText() = textInputEditText {}
inline fun ViewManager.textInputEditText(theme: Int = 0, init: TextInputEditText.() -> Unit) = ankoView({ TextInputEditText(it) }, theme, init)

inline fun ViewManager.textInputLayout() = textInputLayout {}
inline fun ViewManager.textInputLayout(theme: Int = 0, init: TextInputLayout.() -> Unit) = ankoView({ TextInputLayout(it) }, theme, init)
```

Hope this helps

EDIT : based on the comment of @A Boschman, anko is very new and there is almost no documentation. When I had the same problem and I search a lot all over internet but didn't find any documentation.
My Solution is based on below mention thread on GitHub -  (there also no theoritical explanation)

https://github.com/Kotlin/anko/issues/205
https://github.com/Kotlin/anko/issues/264

Comment: Could you please elaborate? Why does this work? Please note that code-only answers are not generally considered very helpful.

Answer (score 3):

`TextInputLayout` is in the Design Support Library, so you need an additional Anko dependency that gives you bindings for that library (you can find a list of all the different Anko packages [here](https://github.com/Kotlin/anko#gradle-based-project)):

```
compile "org.jetbrains.anko:anko-design:$anko_version"
```

You'll also need the [Design Support Library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/packages.html#design) itself if you don't have it yet:

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.4.0'
```